# How to make tkinter gui multiple choice questions on Second frame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create Multiple choice questions under the Question label of Question frame, does anyone know how to create these it would help a-lot thanks, its for a school assessment for me to create a Capital Quiz to ask question on capital countries with multiple choice for user to click on and keep track of the score if they get it correct as well thanks. My code so far for my CapitalQuiz so far is listed below. I want to make a Capital Quiz that after the user enters their name and age they click the next radio button that will bring them to the question frame where they will be presented with multiple choice questions for them to answer and keep track of score record on another frame thanks.

```py
class CapitalQuiz:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        
        
        self.Welcome = Frame(parent)
        self.Welcome.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.TitleLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Welcome to Capital Quiz",
                                bg = "black", fg = "white", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10, font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
        self.TitleLabel.grid(columnspan = 2)
            
        self.NextButton = ttk.Button(self.Welcome, text = 'Next', command = self.show_Questions)
        self.NextButton.grid(row = 8, column = 1)
        
        self.Questions = Frame(parent)
        
        self.QuestionsLabel = Label(self.Questions, text = "Quiz Questions",
                                    bg = "black", fg = "white", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10,
                                    font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
        self.QuestionsLabel.grid(columnspan = 2)
        
        self.HomeButton = ttk.Button(self.Questions, text = 'Home', command = self.show_Welcome)
        self.HomeButton.grid(row = 8, column = 1)
        
        
    def show_Welcome(self):
        self.Questions.grid_remove()
        self.Welcome.grid()
        
    def show_Questions(self):
        self.Welcome.grid_remove()
        self.Questions.grid()
```

The last part of the code I cannot type the code on here so I provided a image for the current quiz to run so far, add this code at the very end of the code to run the quiz after the define functions.

[lastpartofcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaaDY.png)

Comment: Posting an image of code to work around site requirements is not the way to ask a good question.

Comment: The image shows text. It would be better to have the text code so it can be searched.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
class CapitalQuiz:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        
        self.parent = parent
        self.Welcome = Frame(self.parent)
        self.Welcome.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        
        self.TitleLabel = Label(self.Welcome, text = "Welcome to Capital Quiz",
                                bg = "black", fg = "white", font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
        self.TitleLabel.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)
            
        self.NextButton = ttk.Button(self.Welcome, text = 'Next', command = self.show_Questions)
        self.NextButton.place(x=20,y=60)
        
        self.Questions = Frame(self.parent)
        
        self.QuestionsLabel = Label(self.Questions, text = "Questions",
                                    bg = "black", fg = "white", width = 20, padx = 30, pady = 10,
                                    font = ("Time", '14', "bold italic"))
        self.once_done=False
        self.QuestionsLabel.pack(side=TOP,fill=X,anchor="w")
        
        Label(self.Questions, text = "Q1.  What is the capital of United States?",font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=10,y=50)
        self.capital_one=StringVar()
        self.capital_one.set("hellow")
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Washington DC",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_one,value="Washington DC").place(x=20,y=80)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="London",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_one,value="London").place(x=20,y=110)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Delhi",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_one,value="Delhi").place(x=20,y=140)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Tokyo",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_one,value="Tokyo").place(x=20,y=170)
        Label(self.Questions, text = "Q2.  What is the capital of Russia?",font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=10,y=200)
        self.capital_two=StringVar()
        self.capital_two.set("hellow")
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Moscow",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_two,value="Moscow").place(x=20,y=230)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Islamabad",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_two,value="Islamabad").place(x=20,y=260)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Delhi",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_two,value="Delhi").place(x=20,y=290)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Tokyo",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_two,value="Tokyo").place(x=20,y=320)
        Label(self.Questions, text = "Q3.  New Delhi is the capital of which country?",font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=10,y=350)
        self.capital_three=StringVar()
        self.capital_three.set("hellow")
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="India",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_three,value="India").place(x=20,y=380)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Canada",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_three,value="Canada").place(x=20,y=410)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Japan",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_three,value="Japan").place(x=20,y=440)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Spain",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_three,value="Spain").place(x=20,y=470)
        Label(self.Questions, text = "Q4.  What is the capital of Canada?",font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=10,y=500)
        self.capital_four=StringVar()
        self.capital_four.set("hellow")
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Ottawa",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_four,value="Ottawa").place(x=20,y=530)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Paris",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_four,value="Paris").place(x=20,y=560)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Madrid",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_four,value="Madrid").place(x=20,y=590)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="Beijing",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_four,value="Beijing").place(x=20,y=620)
        Label(self.Questions, text = "Q5.  State True or False: Beijing is the capital of China?",font=("arial",12,"bold")).place(x=10,y=650)
        self.capital_five=StringVar()
        self.capital_five.set("hellow")
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="True",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_five,value="True").place(x=20,y=680)
        Radiobutton(self.Questions,text="False",font=("arial",12),variable=self.capital_five,value="False").place(x=20,y=710)
        self.HomeButton = ttk.Button(self.Questions, text = 'Home', command = self.show_Welcome)
        self.HomeButton.place(x=30,y=760)
        self.SubmitButton = ttk.Button(self.Questions, text = 'Submit', command = self.submit)
        self.SubmitButton.place(x=130,y=760)
            
    def submit(self):
        count=0
        if self.capital_one.get()=="Washington DC":
            count+=1
        if self.capital_two.get()=="Moscow":
            count+=1
        if self.capital_three.get()=="India":
            count+=1
        if self.capital_four.get()=="Ottawa":
            count+=1
        if self.capital_five.get()=="True":
            count+=1
        Label(self.Questions,font=("arial",40,"bold"),text=f"You scored: {str(count)}/5").place(x=500,y=50)
        self.c=count
        self.capital_five.set("hellow")
        self.capital_four.set("hellow")
        self.capital_three.set("hellow")
        self.capital_two.set("hellow")
        self.capital_one.set("hellow")
        self.once_done=True
        self.SubmitButton.config(state=DISABLED)
        
    def show_Welcome(self):
        if self.once_done==True:
            for i in self.Questions.winfo_children():
                i.destroy()
            self.Questions.pack_forget()
        else:
            self.Questions.pack_forget()
        self.Welcome.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
        
    def show_Questions(self):
        self.Welcome.pack_forget()
        if self.once_done==True:
            self.Questions.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
            Label(self.Questions,font=("arial",40,"bold"),text=f"You scored: {str(self.c)}/5").place(x=500,y=50)
            Label(self.Questions,font=("arial",30,"bold"),text="You can only attempt the quiz once.").place(x=500,y=160)
        else:
            self.Questions.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)
if __name__ =="__main__":
    root = Tk()

    frames = CapitalQuiz(root)
    root. title("Quiz")
    root . mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you modify and send me the code for putting the multiple choice questions from question frames into seperate frames for example question 1 in frame 1, question 2 in frame 2, question 3 in frame 3 etc. Thanks @Sujay

Comment: No worries, I am busy so I will send it to you after some time.

Comment: Can you send it to me sometime this week as I have a progress check to be made for next week I don't wanna rush you but just saying I need it sometime this week @Sujay

Comment: Can you also add like a message to display to someone if they dont select one of the multiple choice answer and just clicks submit a message will pop up to prevent errors thanks @Sujay

Comment: @P_Wong, https://github.com/ruchirpadhye/Quiz/tree/Ruchir Here. Refer to this code for the quiz